# Read from STDIN in ARMSim#

Tags: assembly, arm

I am doing ARM ASM in ARMSim#. I wanted to take a integer as input from STDIN and process. I was able to do it for a file, but from STDIN it isn't working.
The Reading Snippet

```
myFile: .asciz "sss.txt"
InFileError: .asciz "Unable to open input file\n"
InputFileHandle:.word 0

 @ ========= Open file for reading =============================
ldr R0,=myFile        
mov R1,#0       
swi SWI_Open          @ open file
bcs InFileError       @ if cannot open file branch to InFileError 
ldr R1,=InputFileHandle
str R0,[R1]
ldr R0,=InputFileHandle
ldr R0,[R0]
swi SWI_ReadInt
```

The code doesn't work if I load R0 with #0 instead of Input File, which is supposed to be the file descriptor for STDIN. Please Help

Comment: You mean you did `mov R0, #0; swi SWI_ReadInt`, right?

Comment: I did mov R0,#0; swi SWI_ReadInt

Comment: Yeah that looks okay.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't seem to work here either. As a workaround, maybe you can use `SWI 0x7` to read an integer although for me that doesn't work either.